# Remove shortcut for Jupyter

Tags: keyboard, jupyter, shortcut, unbind

I use Jupyter lab on OSX with a Swiss-German keyboard layout;
in this layout the '@' character is bound to the operation «Jump to line».
How can I unbind this shortcut (globally)?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the keyboard shortcut in the Menu bar: ***Help*** - ***Edit Keyboard Shortcuts***.[image: Jupyter-Help-Keyboard Shortcut]

Another option is using the JupyterLab, the next-generation notebook interface and you can customize it using JSON format in the ***User Preferences*** section.